# i am making an online attendance system

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?PHP
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["teacher"] = "tech01";
        echo "Favorite teacher is " . $_SESSION["teacher"] . ".<br>";
        include 'db.php';
        ?>
        <html>
        <head></head>
            <body>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
            $inst=$_POST['inst'];
            $sub=$_POST['sub'];
            $view_student="select s_name from students where s_inst='$inst' AND 
            s_sub='$sub' ";
            $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$view_student);    
            echo "<form name='form' action='atte.php' method='post'>";  
            echo '<input type="date" name="att">'; // currently for future use
            echo "</br>";
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
            $name=$row['s_name'];
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="present" >';
            echo "<label>" .$name. "</label>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='stun' value='".$name."'/>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='inst' value='".$inst."'/>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='sub' value='".$sub."'/>";
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit_attendance" 
            name="insert">';
            echo "<br>";
            }
            echo "</form>";}
?>
```

Whenever I mark the student present, it marks all student present and how can I save it?
This is the code for online attendance management system.

Comment: I have updated my code in case you were encountering problems with it.

Comment: thanks a lot it is working

Answer (score 0):

Three things you need to change:

1. You are only selecting the name from the database. You should also
   select the primary key (i.e. student_id)
2. Once you have the student_id, shape the names of your form elements to mimic an array-like structure.
3. In your PHP code you can loop through each id and value of the array with a key/value foreach loop.

For step 2 above you should modify your existing code from this:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="present" >';
```

to this:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='present[{student_id}]' >";
```

Notice that the echo statement uses double quotes instead of single quotes to allow for the variable student_id to be interpreted.

For step 3 above:

```
foreach($_POST['present'] as $student_id => $present) {
    if ($present) {
        echo "The student with id of $student_id is present";
    }
}
```